# htaccess - Redirect domain HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect `https://sampledomain.com.au` OR `https://www.sampledomain.com.au` to `http://www.sampledomain.com`

So far this is my .htaccess condition but it's not working:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sampledomain\.com\.au$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.sampledomain\.com\.au$
RewriteRule (.*) http://sampledomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What seems to be the problem/error? Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

This single rule will meet both the requirements:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sampledomain\.com\.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.sampledomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Hi @anubhava I tried your solution and it redirected to this one:
https : // sampledomain.com.au/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi

Not sure why is that happening.

Comment: That might be be due to your other rules and config. As you can see there is no reference to `cgi` here. Post your full .htaccess in question.

Comment: I checked the .htaccess and there is no redirect to any "defaultwebpage.cgi". Maybe the website SSL is not legit, not existing or not properly configured?

Comment: SSL configuration cannot add `/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi`. It could be only due to some code/faulty rules.

Comment: we'll try to buy an SSL certificate so that we'll have https then try to add an index.html or index.php so that if https: // sampledomain.com.au is accessed then index.html will be read then it will do the redirect hopefully to http://www.sampledomain.com

Answer (score 0):

You better try this

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

**Upvote if worked**

Comment: Hi @Ujjwal I tried your answer and got redirected to: https : // sampledomain.com.au/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi too

Comment: @marknt15 please search defaultwebpage.cgi on whole folder of you site.You may find the code. and remove if not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The following finally solved problem for me:

Redirecting all **https** and/OR **www** requests to **non-https** and **non-www** and all its subdirectories.

**https://sampledomain.com.au/**            to  **http://sampledomain.com.au/**

**https://www.sampledomain.com.au/**   to  **http://sampledomain.com.au/**

**http://www.sampledomain.com.au/**     to  **http://sampledomain.com.au/**

added to my **.htaccess** file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.sampledomain.com.au [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://sampledomain.com.au/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Mind you, **NOT escaping** the **"."** with **"\."** in the RewriteCond

Worked on my shared hosting (escaping the "." with "\." did not work on my hosting, to my surprise)

Comment: It's not working